# how to access data from scope object

Tags: angularjs

I need to get data from $scope.List2 object:

```
<div ng-app="App">
  <div id="firstlist" ng-controller="Controller">
    <table id="requesttable" class="RequestTable">
      <tr ng-repeat="item2 in List2">
        <td class="selectedItem">{{item2.Title}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button id="Reqbutton" onclick="SendRequest()">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that if I put SendRequest function inside controller then it cannot be called (I get "SendRequest() is not defined" message). And if I put the function outside the controller I cannot access List2.
What do I miss?

Comment: Attach `SendRequest` to your `$scope` and use `ng-click` instead of `click`. But before, follow the whole [tutorial](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sp00m suggested. You should use `ng-click` instead of `onclick` on the button. The html would look like this then:

```
<button id="Reqbutton" ng-click="sendRequest()">Send</button>
```

In your controller

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function {
    $scope.list2 = [];

    $scope.sendRequest = function() {
        var test = $scope.list2;    
        ...
    };

}]);
```